# Nautilus change search-on-type 3.6.3

Tags: nautilus, 13.04

I have recently upgraded to ubuntu 13.04, and there are some slightly annoying things in nautilus 3.6.3.

Before upgrading I usually did file managment mostly through typing and pressing enter, but in nauiltus 3.6.3 when I type it opens up a deep search, which is slow and not at all what I want.

For instance if I type 'doc' when on my home folder, it will take around 1 minute just to look through all the sub folders before actually selecting documents from my home folder.

I just want it to have the old function of search only within the current folder when I type, or just selecting the one that starts with what I typed.

Is there a way to disable deep-searching and only search in the current directory when typing in nautilus 3.6.3? Without downgrading nautilus.

I do like the sub directory searching in nautilus 3.6.3, but it is super slow compared to just searching the current directory.